Is this the correct Jacobian matrix for the following system?
As I'm working on a homework problem, I have the following system
\begin{cases} \dot{x}=y\\\dot{y}=-x-\epsilon(\alpha x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3)
\end{cases}In order to find the Jacobian matrix, I've got $$J=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial y'}{\partial x} \frac{\partial y'}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ since this is a linear system, I've neglected the nonlinear terms of $-\epsilon(\alpha x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3)$. Is this the correct Jacobian matrix?

There is a lot of context missing. You can't "neglect" the nonlinear terms. You have to figure out which points (in different contexts critical points or stationary points are the terms) you are linearizing about. In a vacuum, a nonlinear system does not have a global Jacobian matrix attached to it at all because those are two separate concepts.

Yes, your helpful hint(s) have given me the right/correct direction of solving this problem. I've got it now. Thank you!

Just to check, there should be $3$ Jacobians - one at each of the three stationary points. Also helpful is that $\frac{d}{dx}x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x) = 2|x|$. Did you figure out which one(s) you needed?

Yes, that's correct.

The Jacobian matrix is
$$
J(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 - \epsilon(2\alpha|x| + 3\beta x^2)& 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
You can evaluate this at each critical point to determine the linearized systems.

Thank you very much!
